# taking averages of certain indices using another list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I was hoping to take the average of a list using another list with the start and stop indices.

for example:

```
a = [3, 9]

b = [0, 1, 12, 9, 0, 8, 9, 3, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 6]
```

I want to take the average of the numbers from `b[3] to b[9]` and this is what I have so far

```
counter = a[0]
sum = b[counter]
while counter < a[1] + 1:
   counter += 1
   sum = sum + b[counter]
denominator = a[1] - a[0] + 1
avg = sum/denominator
```

But after checking, it seems to be giving the wrong thing

Comment: What are the expected and actual outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `statistics.mean`

```
from statistics import mean
a = [3, 9]

b = [0, 1, 12, 9, 0, 8, 9, 3, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 6]
mean(b[a[0]: a[1] + 1])
```

or you could use:

```
sum(b[a[0]: a[1] + 1]) / len(b[a[0]: a[1] + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
from statistics import mean
a = [3, 9]
b = [0, 1, 12, 9, 0, 8, 9, 3, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 6]
avg = mean(b[a[0]:a[1]+1])
print (avg)
```